# adding new columns a csv file using pandas and dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I would like to rewrite a csv file by adding new headers and contents from two different dictionary, but It seems to not work:

```
df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], na_values = ['no info', '.'], encoding='Cp1252', delimiter=';')
f=pd.DataFrame(d_filtered_words).T.reset_index()
f.columns=['id','filtered_words']
df=pd.concat([df,f],axis=1)
df.to_csv('result.csv', sep=';', encoding='Cp1252')

df = pd.read_csv('result.csv', na_values = ['no info', '.'], encoding='Cp1252', delimiter=';')
s=pd.DataFrame(d_score).T.reset_index()
s.columns=['id','ScorePos','Scoreneg','Scoreneu']
df=pd.concat([df,s],axis=1)
df.to_csv('result2.csv', sep=';', encoding='Cp1252')
```

the input file looks like this (it is too long , i just write an example:

```
numero;nom
1;marie
2;noemie
```

expected result

```
numero;nom;id;filtered_words;id;ScorePos;Scoreneg;Scoreneu
1;marie;1;marie;1;25;58;569
2;noemie;2;noemie;56;789;25
```

error in the code :

the values in the dico are not the same but that' normal they contains different Numbers of words, i cannot change them ,the data are like that

```
    s=pd.DataFrame(d_filtered_words).T.reset_index()
  File "C:\Users\Em\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 348, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Em\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 459, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Em\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7356, in _arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\Users\Em\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7402, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('arrays must all be same length')
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Comment: Looks like merging dataframes with `pd.merge` better fits your needs, than concat

Comment: @koPytok but at which level I use it  :df=pd.merge([df,f],axis=1); the problem seems to be this line  : f=pd.DataFrame(d_filtered_words).T.reset_index() but i do not know why